# How do I install this TikZ/PGF package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, mactex

I'm having difficulty in figuring out how to install the TikZ package on my mac (i just need to draw some diagrams under the environment {tikzpicture}), the file that I have downloaded (http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/) is not just a .sty file. There are lot of files inside the folder. Furthermore, I have only installed MacTeX.

Sorry if the question is trivial and thanks in advance.

Comment: TikZ is installed as part of MacTeX as standard: have you tried to use it before messing about with extra downloads?

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, but apparently it's not installed.

Comment: Did you do a full MacTeX install? If so and if TikZ is missing then something has gone wrong with the installation. What exactly did you try to see if it's installed?

Comment: @JosephWright Yes and I tried to include the package tikz but it does not identify it when compiling.

Comment: If `\listfiles\documentclass{article}\usepackage{tikz}\begin{document}\end{document}` doesn't work then you've got a defective installation. I'd be tempted to remove it and try again: there are probably other issues lurking.

Comment: @JosephWright OK thanks, I will try installing again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start Tex Live Utility (a program on your mac and part of MacTeX) and update all packages.

Comment: As MacTeX does a full install of TeX Live, not having TikZ suggests something has gone wrong. Hence my suggestion to reinstall: you've no idea what else might be wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry. This is a wrong answer. `tikzit` is an TikZ/PGF editor, not TikZ/PGF.

You can install TikZ throgh Homebrew

```
brew install --cask tikzit
```

[tikzit — Homebrew Formulae](https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/tikzit)

Comment: This is wrong, TikZ**it** is a different tool, TikZ is a (La)TeX library.